# exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

Tags: rest, tomcat, jersey

I just made my first REST api based on this http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html
I am using eclipse kepler, tomcat7, and Jersey

when I try to "Run on server" I get this error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet /de.vogella.jersey.first threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the source code:

```
package de.vogella.jersey.first;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }

}
```

here is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>de.vogella.jersey.first</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>de.vogella.jersey.first</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

here are the libraries that I have added from Jersey:

```
asm-all-repackaged-2.2.0-b14.jar
cglib-2.2.0-b14.jar
guava-14.0.1.jar
hk2-api-2.2.0-b14.jar
hk2-locator-2.2.0-b14.jar
hk2-utils-2.2.0-b14.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.inject-2.2.0-b14.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar
jersey-client.jar
jersey-common.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
jersey-container-servlet.jar
jersey-server.jar
org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar
osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
persistence-api-1.0.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

Comment: This should solve your issue....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086218/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-jersey-spi-container-servlet-servletco

Answer (score 6):

If you are using jersey 2.x API, you need to rename the classes as done below, and your issue will be resolved.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>org.glassfish.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.practise.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Karthik [aka DjNickZ]

Answer (score 2):

You are getting

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
```

That means you are using different version of `jar`. You added `jersey-server.jar` this `jar`  is upgrade to `jersey-servlet-1.17.jar`.

So add [jersey-servlet-1.17.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjerseyservlet117jar.htm) to your project.

Answer (score 1):

We get this error because of build path issue. You should add "Server Runtime" libraries in Build Path.

"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer"

Please follow below steps to resolve class not found exception.

Right click on project --> Build Path --> Java Build Path --> Add Library --> Server Runtime --> Apache Tomcat v7.0

Thanks,
Sachin G N

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following jar files to your web-inf/lib folder, also you need to configure build path -- Right click your project--Build path -- configure build path -- libraries -- add external jars (add all the below jar files). And restart server

[image: Jersey libs]