# docx-html-editor: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.plutext.htmleditor.JAXRS2Application

Tags: java, docx4j

I am playing around with docx-html-editor (part of the docx4j project) and I am having problems running the application. The start up page loads fine but when i select a document it is throwing the following exception:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet [services] in web application [/docx-html-editor] threw load() exception
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.plutext.htmleditor.JAXRS2Application
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1856)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1705)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$6.run(ReflectionHelper.java:376)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$6.run(ReflectionHelper.java:366)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:403)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:275)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried the following solution and it worked for a while.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31887840/2533611

The same exception re-occured when i changed docx4j version and reverting back to the previous version did not solve the problem.

I suspect it might be my project properties. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you included the project properly?

Comment: @RohitArya I deleted the project and reincluded the project. It is now fine. I suspect i messed up the project properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reimported a clean copy of the project and now it works fine. I probably messed up on the project properties. If anyone is encountering the same error, try the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31887840/2533611