# ClassNotFoundException with using jersey in J2EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, classnotfoundexception

I try to use jersey web services in my J2EE application but this strange exception appears:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
```

My pom.xml file is as following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>test</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- javax: XML binding -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- RESTful web service: Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Unit testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>test</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
       version="3.0">
<!-- Servlets -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.ocs.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What i wrong in my code?! I check the version of jersey and it is the correct version to use *com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer* in web.xml!

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086218/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-jersey-spi-container-servlet-servletco)

Comment: I use version 1.17.1 of jersey as you can see in my pom.xml file. Your reference's solution is what I have done and don't know why still exception appears :(

Comment: Since you shared web.xml, I assume your JEE application is packed into WAR. It is possible that you did not pack jersey-servlet.jar into WEB-INF/lib. Check out your Maven WAR build configuration.