# SEVERE: Error loading WebappClassLoader

Tags: java, web-services, maven, tomcat, servlets

I am developing a webservice using JAX-RS RESTEasy using java.I am getting the following error(as showed inside my stacktrace).
I have firstly used jersey_bundle-1.17.1 maven as described at [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086218/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-jersey-spi-container-servlet-servletco) here.Before that i am used jersey_bundle-1.12.Both of them wont works.After that as per the error i have searched for com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer package inside jarfiles and it found at there.But i am using maven and i searched inside maven and it not found at there(But i added those to my pom.xml).Is that my problem?If it is how to resolve that error?Or else what is my problem i am not getting any clue about that(Spend more than 14 hours) on it.Any help will be highly appreciable...
NB:I am using tomcat-v 6.0 server

Stacktrace

```
pr 16, 2015 11:43:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;D:\java\eclipse\eclipse;;.
Apr 16, 2015 11:43:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SnapshotHealthApp' did not find a matching property.
Apr 16, 2015 11:43:54 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-9999
Apr 16, 2015 11:43:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 439 ms
Apr 16, 2015 11:43:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 16, 2015 11:43:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.43
Apr 16, 2015 11:43:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet jersey-servlet as unavailable
Apr 16, 2015 11:43:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Error loading WebappClassLoader
  context: /SnapshotHealthApp
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@5a384a
 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Apr 16, 2015 11:43:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /SnapshotHealthApp threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Apr 16, 2015 11:43:55 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-9999
Apr 16, 2015 11:43:55 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Apr 16, 2015 11:43:55 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/32  config=null
Apr 16, 2015 11:43:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 276 ms
```

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>snapshot</groupId>
  <artifactId>snapshot</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
          <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
          <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
       </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.14</version>
</dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.8.2</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.codesnippets4all</groupId>
    <artifactId>quick-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20141113</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
   <finalName>SnapshotHealthApp</finalName>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                <compilerVersion>1.5</compilerVersion>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
             </configuration>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SnapshotHealthApp</display-name>
  <servlet>

    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.snapshothealthapp.controller</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you please open up your WAR file and check to see if the required Jersey dependencies are there?  Your POM looks fine to me.

Comment: TimBiegeleisen  I will check it and replay.
I have one more dobt.Can you please check my web.xml for checking my servelet name.especially my <servelet-class> that i defined........That thing is showed as error inside my application.In somewhere else i found that org.glassfish.etc....contains that com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.I am using tomcat 6.0

Comment: Your `web.xml` looks fine.  If this were a problem, you would be getting errors from trying to instantiate the `ServletContainer` class.  Please check the WAR which is being deployed; I'll bet it is missing the Jersey dependencies.

Comment: ok Tim Biegeleisen.about getting errors from trying to instantiate the ServletContainer...thankyou.I will check my WAR and will reply surely...

Comment: Check also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086218/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-jersey-spi-container-servlet-servletco?lq=1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can just see a web-inf and meta-inf while extracting war files.cannot able to see jar files inside it(I am new to web application development ).

Comment: Please view [this site](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/jxslt/ch06_02.htm) to understand the WAR structure.  Open your WAR using 7-zip or a similar tool.  We must determine whether or not your WAR has the required Jersey libraries.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen extracted war file as the way you mentioned above.It shows classes,web.xml and library.My LIBRARY folder is empty.

Comment: Bingo!  OK...how are you generating your WAR using Maven?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Maven is contained under my project folder(inside eclipse).So i just Right clicked Projectname>export>web>warfile>finish.Is there anything wrong?(At the begining stage i right clicked projectname and make that project as maven dependent)

Comment: Please research what could be the cause of your missing dependencies.  Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75367/discussion-between-tim-biegeleisen-and-vishnu-m).