# error with a jersey restful maven project

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey, wildfly

I downloaded the project from [mkyong's](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/) website. I'm facing issue running the project. I'm not sure what is wrong. I'm doing this the first time, so please help me. If this works, I want to add hibernate to this project.

I tried to deploy this in Glassfish server and Wildfly 10. Didn't work in either of the servers

**pom.xml**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>RESTfulExample</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RESTfulExample Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>RESTfulExample</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**HelloWorldService.java**

```
package com.mkyong.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**[image: web.xml]**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Jersey 1.x configuration for Jersey 2.x dependencies. It won't work. The two major versions have no compatibility whatsoever. 2.x configuration looks more like

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.mkyong.rest
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

See more at [Servlet-based Deployment](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet).

**A few other things:**

- You are already using Maven. No need to put jars into the `WEB-INF/lib` yourself.
- If you are using Glassfish, you should put *all* the Jersey dependencies you are using in a `provided` `<scope>`

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```

  The reason is that Glassfish already uses Jersey as the JAX-RS implementation, but it uses an older version (with GF 4.1 its 2.10.4). You don't want a different version to cause conflicts. If you want to upgrade Jersey in Glassfish, you can check out [Updating Jersey 2 in GlassFish 4](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/01/21/updating-jersey-2-in-glassfish-4/)
- If you want to use Wildfly, it already uses RESTeasy as JAX-RS implementation. To use Jersey you should disable RESTeasy. Not completely sure the best way to go about doing that. You may need to do some googling.
- If you were to just use a plain servlet container like Tomcat, you can leave the dependencies as is, without `<scope>provided</scope>`, as Tomcat doesn't have a JAX-RS implementation.

Comment: It didn't work for me, I changed servlet-class to `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer`, and also param-name to `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` but no luck

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: Also you need to add a "param" to the end of your URL, for example `/rest/hello/something`, because of `@Path("/{param}")`

Comment: i'm using Pivotal tc Server Deployment that came with Spring Source Tool Suite. the URL I have is `http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/hello/world`

Comment: With your current pom.xml file, and the new web.xml, and taking out the jars in the lib, there's no reason it shouldn't work, unless there is a deployment issue with the IDE/server

Comment: Is there anything in the server log when you launch the server that says there is a problem?

Comment: The jars are created when I ran the Maven Install in the eclipse. Do I have to mvn clean and deploy to the server ?

Comment: I don't know. It's been a while since I used eclipse. I didn't know it copies the jars to the lib. I know Maven should copy them to the final war, but I didn't know that eclipse will display them in the project.

Comment: One thing to note is that if what is in your image of the lib is what Eclipse copies and uses, then not all the jars are getting copied. Those are not all the jars that come with all the Maven dependencies you declared. And it is not enough jars to run your app. The image is missing some Jersey jars

Comment: Though it may not solve your problem, you can check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33327308/2587435) for a quick sanity check to see it works, when not using your IDE/IDE-server

Comment: Also, if for any reason you didn't create the project correctly, you see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30020830/2587435) for easy to create a new project. Try to run that project and see what happens

Comment: Creating the project as jersey archetype worked perfectly. Thanks ! :)