# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet

Tags: spring, web-services, maven, tomcat, jersey

I am Try to add RESTFul web services in my Spring web MVC App. I use NetBeans and add web services by using netbeans wizard. my POM as flow

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
            <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ORM integration, e.g Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security JSP Taglib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- connect to mysql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

and my service class

```
@Path("generic")
public class GenericResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of GenericResource
     */
    public GenericResource() {
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of com.trianz.travapp.service.web.GenericResource
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getJson() {
        return "Server Test Web Serives";
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of GenericResource
     * @param content representation for the resource
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void putJson(String content) {
    }
}
```

but class tomcat show error message as follows 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet

on the time of deploy.

what I miss??

Answer (score 0):

the error shows that you're missing the class `com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet` and i think it's a class in the jar that you declared : `<groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
               <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
               <version>1.19</version>`

You should verify in this jar if your class exists or not ? If not another version of your jar`jersey`

Answer (score 0):

it actually depends on jersey version if you are using jersey 2.x then you need another configuration in web.xml. you can update your web.xml with following configuration.

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myrest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>    
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>your.package.path</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
     <param-name>unit:WidgetPU</param-name>
     <param-value>persistence/widget</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myrest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086218/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-jersey-spi-container-servlet-servletco)