# Unable to deploy Restful simple code on Tomcat 7. error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, servlets

I have downloaded and imported jars of **jersey 1.16**, **jersey 1.17** and **jersey2.23** version separately and together(**jersey 2.23** and **jersey 1.16**). The code gets compiled properly but getting the above error when I try to deploy on **Tomcat 7**.

I have referred the following tutorials:

1. RESTful Java client with Jersey client
2. Implementing RESTFul service with Java

If I use only jersey 2.23 jar then it's throwing error. When I import and use Client package hence I added Jersey-Client-1.2.jar to avoid those error and I also added jersey-container-servlet-core jar to Tomcat lib folder. But error is still existing. Error :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
```

Comment: Check this links:http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/classnotfoundexception-com-sun-jersey-spi-container-servlet-servletcontainer/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086218/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-jersey-spi-container-servlet-servletco

Comment: I have tried all of those solution and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, correct the project dependencies in `pom.xml` like below. If you are not using maven for project dependencies, include the corresponding jar files in classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Then you might need to share some more information. check `web-inf/lib` what jar(version) is present?

Comment: Are you using eclipse IDE?

Comment: if you are following eclipse `Right click on project --> Build Path --> Java Build Path --> Add Library --> Server Runtime --> Apache Tomcat v7.0 
` this will fix the issue