# REST WS- SEVERE: Servlet [Jersey] in web application [/RESTfulWebService1] threw load() exception

Tags: web-services, rest, maven, servlets, pom.xml

I am new to WS I am trying to learn and create a RESTful WS in Eclipse IDE.I have followed couple of tutorials from Youtube. I am not able to find any around setting up your environment.On google I followed different posts and learnt about how to set up my env. However I am still failing to get the project deployed successfully.

Please excuse for the stupid question but I am not able to figure out how to resolved this.

I am using Jersey 1.17.1 library and Tomcat 7 server. My deployment is failing. Please help

Below are the artifacts of my project: 
My Class:

```
    package com.service.user;

    import javax.ws.rs.*

    @Path("/user/service")
    public class UserServices { 
        @PUT
        @Path("/create")
        public void creatUser() 
        {}
        @GET
        public void getUser()
        {

            System.out.print("Inside the getUser Method");

        }
        @POST
        public void updateUser()
        {
            System.out.print("Inside the Update user Method");
        }
        @DELETE
        public void deleteUser()
        {}        
    }
```

My Web.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>RESTfulWebService1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.servletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/backend/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

In the process of trying to resolve the error I came across some posts which said that I need Maven. Have converted my project to Maven Project and below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>RESTfulWebService1</groupId>
  <artifactId>RESTfulWebService1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**I am getting this error when I am trying to deploy the project.**

Below is the snipped from Eclipse console

```
Nov 3, 2016 1:28:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [Jersey] in web application [/RESTfulWebService1] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.servletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Nov 3, 2016 1:28:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8091"]
Nov 3, 2016 1:28:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8019"]
Nov 3, 2016 1:28:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1257 ms
```

I tried cleaning and rebuilding a couple of times but no luck.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086218/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-jersey-spi-container-servlet-servletco